# How do I compare two strings to return number of differences?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string

I have two strings:

str1: "password"
str2: "pss$w#rd"

I want to compare both strings and want to print output the total number of differences between them

Output:

> 4

since in str2 "a", "o" removed and "$", "#" is added so total operation is 4.

But my code is giving wrong output. How can I solve this? I might be missing something.

```
def getMinTotalNumChanges(str1, str2):
    # Write your code here
    totalCount = 0
    
    sorted(str1)
    sorted(str2)
    
    for i in str1:
        for j in str2:
            if i != j:
                totalCount += 1
    return totalCount
    
# driver code
str1 = "password"
str2 = "pss$wr#d"
print(getMinTotalNumChanges(str1, str2))
```

Comment: Didn't you [ask this already?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64736562/3890632)

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Check insertion and deletion in new password. How to perform such string manipiluation in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64736562/check-insertion-and-deletion-in-new-password-how-to-perform-such-string-manipil)

Comment: At your current rate of asking, with the downvotes you are receiving, I would imagine you will shortly be entering an automatic question ban.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily do it by sets but it will ignore the difference of repeated characters and position difference like str1: "password" str2: "ps$w#rd" will also give you result 4. Please look into this code:

```
def getMinTotalNumChanges(str1, str2):
    str1_set= set(str1)
    str2_set= set(str2)
    str_intersection=str1_set.intersection(str2_set)
    diff1=str1_set - str_intersection
    diff2=str2_set - str_intersection
    total_diff= len(diff1)+len(diff2)
    return total_diff


str1 = "password"
str2 = "pss$wr#d"
print(getMinTotalNumChanges(str1, str2))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Qamar. This worked for me. I appreciate it.

Comment: This code doesn't work. `getMinTotalNumChanges("s", "sss")` is 0, when it should be 2. Likewise, `getMinTotalNumChanges("abc", "acb")` is 0, when it should be 2. Also, `getMinTotalNumChanges("fooo", "foaa")` is 1, when it should be 2.

Comment: Why are you using sets? You're going to lose information on repeated characters.

Comment: Yes, it will not work for the cases you mentioned. it needs elaboration from the user, but i hope it worked. This  code will only return the number of difference between the string !

Answer (score 2):

This is a pretty simple DP problem, where you just have to check for deletion, edits, and insertions:

```py
def getMinTotalNumChanges(str1, str2, memo=None):
    if memo is None:
        memo = {}
    if str1 == "":
        return len(str2)
    if str2 == "":
        return len(str1)
    if (str1, str2) in memo:
        return memo[(str1, str2)]
    diff = 1 if str1[0] != str2[0] else 0
    ret = min(
        # deletion
        1 + getMinTotalNumChanges(str1[1:], str2, memo),
        # edit
        diff + getMinTotalNumChanges(str1[1:], str2[1:], memo),
        # insertion
        1 + getMinTotalNumChanges(str1, str2[1:], memo)
    )
    memo[(str1, str2)] = ret
    return ret


str1 = "password"
str2 = "pss$wr#d"
print(getMinTotalNumChanges(str1, str2))
```

Comment: What is "DP"? Could you edit a clarification into this answer?